# How to solve array problem to check if element is greater, less than or equal its neighbor

Tags: python, algorithm, conditional-statements

I'm still learning more about programming and have a problem with my code.

I have an array

data = [5,4,4,4,4,3,3,8] the expected result should be P,n,n,n,n,n,v,p. but I'm getting this p,n,n,n,p,n,n,p

#data = [2,1,4,5,5,5,4]  expected result p,v,n,n,n,p,v (my code works for this. but the code must be able to solve the two)

I want to assign them to Peak(P) and Valley(V).

where the peak is the high number and Valley is the lower number.

.

```
def get_Ps_values(data):
    dt=[]
    details=[]
    n = len(data)
    #Handling first element in the data
    #We check if first element is less or equal to the next element
    if (data[0] < data[1]):
        #if there is, we append the element to the list
        dt.append(data[0])
        details.append('V')
        
    elif (data[0] > data[1]):
        dt.append(data[0])
        details.append('P')
        
    else:
        #this is checking if the first element is a P
        dt.append(data[1])
        details.append('N')
   #To handle other elements in the data that are not first and last element
    for i in range(1, n-1):
            if data[i] == data[i-1]==data[i+1]:
                dt.append(data[i])
                details.append('N')
            elif data[i] < data[i-1]<data[i+1]:
                dt.append(data[i])
                details.append('V')
            elif i+1 > n-1 and data[i+1] > data[i-1]:

                dt.append(data[i])
                details.append('P')
            elif (i == 1 or data[i-1] == data[i]) and (i == n-1 or data[i] > data[i+1]):  # Found peak
                dt.append(data[i])
                details.append('P')
            elif i-1 > n-1 and data[i+1] < data[i-1]:

                dt.append(data[i])
                details.append('V')
            else:
                dt.append(data[i])
                details.append('N')
    
    #Handling last element in the data
    #We check if the last element is greater or equal to the element before it.
    if (data[-1] > data[-2]):
        #if there is, we append the element to the list
        dt.append(data[-1])
        details.append('P')
        
    elif(data[-1] < data[-2]):
        #if there is, we append the element to the list
        dt.append(data[-1])
        details.append('N')
    elif(data[-1] >= data[-2]):
        #if there is, we append the element to the list
        dt.append(data[-1])
        details.append('V')
   
        #this is checking if the last element is a V
        dt.append(data[-1])
        details.append('N')

    return dt, details
```

Thanks

Comment: Do define *precisely* what you call a peak and a valley.

Comment: Have done that already .. a peak is a high number, while the valley is a lower number.    just as in 4516 where 4 is lower than 5 . reading from the left

Comment: I cannot match the data you sent to the expected result. If the data set has 8 values, the expected result should imho have only 7.

Comment: It doesn't. I have edited it now. the expected value was down before.

Comment: Sorry but you don't realize that this definition is incomplete.  Is 01110 a peak ? Where is it ? What is 000 ? What is 001 ?

Comment: in 01110, 0 is the valley why 1 is the peak   the result should be v,n,n,p,v

Comment: What about the others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- that a peak is the **last** point of a stretch of identical values if it is strictly **higher** than the previous and next stretches (or of only one neighbor on the ends)
- that is valley is the same for a strictly **lower** value compared to the neighbor(s)
- all other points being "n"

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to compare the stretches to the previous and next ones:

```
from itertools import groupby

def pvn(data):
    out = []
    pos = 0
    prev = None
    for k, g in groupby(data):
        g = list(g)
        pos = pos + len(g)
        next_ = data[pos] if pos < len(data) else None
        if (prev is None or k > prev) and (next_ is None or k > next_):
            out.extend(['n']*(len(g)-1)+['p'])
        elif (prev is None or k < prev) and (next_ is None or k < next_):
            out.extend(['n']*(len(g)-1)+['v'])
        else:
            out.extend(['n']*len(g))
        prev = k
    return out

pvn([5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 8])
# ['p', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'v', 'p']

pvn([2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4])
# ['p', 'v', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'p', 'v']
```

Comment: Thanks ... It works .. Please I will love it if you can share some links to materials to learn more on programming.